# How to merge only a specific data frame column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I've been trying to use the `pd.merge` function properly but I either receive an error or get the table formatted in a way I don't like. I looked through the documentation but I can't find a way to only merge a specific column. For instance lets say I'm working with these two dataframes.

df_1 = `county_name accidents   pedestrians
              ADAMS         1             2
          ALLEGHENY         1             3
          ARMSTRONG         3             4
            BEDFORD         1             1`

df_2 = `county_name population 
              ADAMS     102336 
          ALLEGHENY    1223048 
          ARMSTRONG      65642 
            BEDFORD     166140 
              BERKS      48480 
              BLAIR     417854 
           BRADFORD     123457 
              BUCKS      60853 
            CAMBRIA     628341`

The outcome im looking for is something like this. Where the county names are added to the 'county_name' column but not duplicated and the 'population' column is left off.

df_outcome = `county_name   accidents   pedestrians
                    ADAMS           1             2
                ALLEGHENY           1             3
                ARMSTRONG           3             4
                  BEDFORD           1             1
                    BERKS         Nan           Nan
                    BLAIR         Nan           Nan
                  BRADFORD        Nan           Nan
                     BUCKS        Nan           Nan
                   CAMBRIA        Nan           Nan`

Lastly, I plan to use `df_outcome.fillna(0)` to replace all the `Nan` values with zero.

Comment: can you copy the data and paste as text? images cant be copied and thus cant be reproduced

Comment: @anky sorry I reposted as text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter column `county_name` and use `merge` with left join:

```
df = df_2[['county_name']].merge(df_1, how='left')
print (df)
  county_name  accidents  pedestrians
0       ADAMS        1.0          2.0
1   ALLEGHENY        1.0          3.0
2   ARMSTRONG        3.0          4.0
3     BEDFORD        1.0          1.0
4       BERKS        NaN          NaN
5       BLAIR        NaN          NaN
6    BRADFORD        NaN          NaN
7       BUCKS        NaN          NaN
8     CAMBRIA        NaN          NaN
```

Comment: @anky_91 This does indeed work but the data from df_1 is all NaN now

Comment: @prime90 - For me working nice, there are not some traling spaces in column `county_name` ? Check it by `print(df1['county_name'].tolist()[:20])`

Comment: @anky_91 Weird I get `ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer` the population column datatype is an `int` so I changed it to `float` and I get empty list brackets `[]`

Comment: @prime90 - What is your code? Can you edit question?

Comment: @anky_91 I was getting an error in my code from a previous edit I forgot I needed to change back. Thank you. This worked great. I had no idea you needed to use double brackets to access a specific column. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2[['county_name']], how='left')
```

Comment: @jezrael If you feel this plagiarized, you should mod flag. The answer is not low quality

Comment: @Machavity - I have negative experience, all my flags(2 times) was declined... :(